# How to order values with order by x asc but if x has a specific number like 3 to make it show last sql

Tags: sql

I have this query

```
  select name, 
         surname, 
         age 
    from user 
order by idcard asc
```

but I want that if `idcard` has values `3` those values to be shown together in the *end* of the list while the rest `1, 2, 4, 5, 6,` to order by `asc`

is it possible to do?

Comment: `order by case when idcard = 3 then 1 else 0 end asc, idcard`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using `case`:

```
   select ...
 order by case
            when idcard = 3 then 1
            else 0
          end,
          idcard
```